# AWS Spark images not supporting HDFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-emr, amazon-eks

I am currently working on running our daily ETLS On EKS instead of EMR. How ever i see few of the jobs are failing (few of them use HDFS). I see the official Docker image provided by AWS doesn't support HDFS.
I am using `895885662937.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/spark/emr-5.32.0` image.

```
bash-4.2$ hdfs
/usr/bin/hdfs: line 8: /usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/bin/hdfs: No such file or directory
```

This are logs for Job fail

```
Jobrun failed. Main Spark container terminated with errors. Last error seen in logs - Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:/bucket-name/process-store/checkpoints/086461cd-df44-4ab4-a2ee-da2c5671f9b4\nCaused by: java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:/bucket-name/process-store/checkpoints/086461cd-df44-4ab4-a2ee-da2c5671f9b4. Please refer logs uploaded to S3/CloudWatch based on your monitoring configuration
```

Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: I suggest creating an EMR support ticket for their own images

Comment: _Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:/bucket-name/pro..._ ? Shouldnt URI be `hdfs://end-point/bucket/path...`?

Comment: @mazaneicha yes in the json file we mentioned as hdfs:// no idea why it is printing as hdfs:/ in output. I am using same json file on EMR there it worked fine.